# Problem with iTextSharp and PdfTable

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I try to use this:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfTable tbl = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfTable();
```

But i always get the error:

```
The type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfTable' has no constructors defined
```

Why that? In various tutorial I saw that that should be possible.

Comment: Which version are you using? A comment to this article suggests, that the class PdfTable has been removed: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables. Comment is: 14 May 2010 21:21 from Mikesdotnetting.

Comment: I dont know exactly but one of the newest. Thanks that solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `PdfPTable` instead. I haven't used iTextSharp myself, but Google suggests, that it's the right class name.